# how get input value of form in associative array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array, submission

There is a form with list wrapper with input tag inside which they are created dynamically.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="action-elements cross-icon"> X </div>
  <input name="term-title" type="text" value="blue" class="action-elements term-title" id="term-title">
  <div class="action-elements term-quantity-price">
    <input name="color_quantity" class="color_quantity" id="color_quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity">
    <input name="color_price" class="color_price" id="color_price" type="number" placeholder="Price">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="action-elements cross-icon"> X </div>
  <input name="term-title" type="text" value="red" class="action-elements term-title" id="term-title">
  <div class="action-elements term-quantity-price">
    <input name="color_quantity" class="color_quantity" id="color_quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity">
    <input name="color_price" class="color_price" id="color_price" type="number" placeholder="Price">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get input in multidimensional array when submit form. something like this

```
array{1:array{term-title:blue, color_quantity:10, color_price:200}, 2:array{term-title:red, color_quantity:20, color_price:30},...}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I assume the there are some form tags and a submit button?

Comment: The script you give, i.e. serializeArray is what I wanted, output object will be send to php by ajax and I can access to all input data properly. Thanks a lot my friend :)

Comment: It was not my script. I explained that the format you wanted is not created by serializeArray. I wrote a more complicated script for you instead, because you wanted `array{1:array{term-title:blue, color_quantity:10, color_price:200}, 2:array{term-title:red, color_quantity:20, color_price:30},...}` which is NOT the output from serializeArray

Comment: I can use both of theme, both are OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the wrapper inside a form tag ? if so please checkout [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

in general if you want to get all the data in the form you can use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

here is an example:

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="action-elements cross-icon"> X </div>
    <input name="term-title" type="text" value="blue" class="action-elements term-title" id="term-title">
    <div class="action-elements term-quantity-price">
      <input name="color_quantity" class="color_quantity" id="color_quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity">
      <input name="color_price" class="color_price" id="color_price" type="number" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="action-elements cross-icon"> X </div>
    <input name="term-title" type="text" value="red" class="action-elements term-title" id="term-title">
    <div class="action-elements term-quantity-price">
      <input name="color_quantity" class="color_quantity" id="color_quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity">
      <input name="color_price" class="color_price" id="color_price" type="number" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That will make a {name:name,value:value} arr

Comment: could you share the result that you get from the console ?

Comment: You could have yourself. Just click edit, then the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: He wants `[[{term-title:blue, color_quantity:10, color_price:200}],[{term-title:red, color_quantity:20, color_price:30}]]`

Comment: Yours give `[
  {
    "name": "term-title",
    "value": "blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "color_quantity",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "color_price",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "term-title",
    "value": "red"
  },
  {
    "name": "color_quantity",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "color_price",
    "value": ""
  }
]`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this

See the difference between this and serializeArray after the example

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myForm").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // remove if you want the form to submit
    const arr = []
    $(".wrapper").each(function(i,div) {
      arr[i] = $(":input",this).map(function() { // OR your can consider $(":input",this).serializeArray()
        return { [$(this).attr("name")]:$(this).val() }
      }).get()
    })
    console.log(arr)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="action-elements cross-icon"> X </div>
    <input name="term-title" type="text" value="blue" class="action-elements term-title" id="term-title">
    <div class="action-elements term-quantity-price">
      <input name="color_quantity" class="color_quantity" id="color_quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity">
      <input name="color_price" class="color_price" id="color_price" type="number" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="action-elements cross-icon"> X </div>
    <input name="term-title" type="text" value="red" class="action-elements term-title" id="term-title">
    <div class="action-elements term-quantity-price">
      <input name="color_quantity" class="color_quantity" id="color_quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity">
      <input name="color_price" class="color_price" id="color_price" type="number" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The above script gives what you asked for

```js
[
  [{
      "term-title": "blue"
    },
    {
      "color_quantity": ""
    },
    {
      "color_price": ""
    }
  ],
  [{
      "term-title": "red"
    },
    {
      "color_quantity": ""
    },
    {
      "color_price": ""
    }
  ]
]
```

You cannot use serializeArray to get your output unless you massage it afterwards

```js
[{
  "name": "term-title",
  "value": "blue"
}, {
  "name": "color_quantity",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "name": "color_price",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "name": "term-title",
  "value": "red"
}, {
  "name": "color_quantity",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "name": "color_price",
  "value": ""
}]
```